# Any utility to check RAM performance?

Tags: memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best computer “burn-in” or stability testing software?](https://superuser.com/questions/8593/what-is-the-best-computer-burn-in-or-stability-testing-software)

Actually these days my system is giving me hard time. I am only running Visual studio 2010 and few other application (like skype, firefox and Perforce) simultaneously. And it gets stalled even if I try to undo changes in the editor. But when I open my task manager and check for usage its only 2.4GB out of 4.00 GB. And even the CPU usage is with in the range of 10-15%.

I have already scaned for spywares and virus on my system, but didn't get any success. Now I want to check whther something has gone wrong with RAM.

So can anyone tell me a good reliable utility to check my RAM Performance.

System config

```
Processor: i5 2nd Generation 
Ram 4 gb
```

Comment: looks more like hard disk problem

Comment: use freeramxp pro  http://www.yourwaresolutions.com/software.html#framxpro

Comment: @gladiator2345 seriously? That doesn't do anything.

Comment: It cannot help check your ram but will help freeing it up by pushing memory to page file.

Comment: @gladiator2345 and what's the point of pushing it to a page file? Slow it down even more?

Comment: @gladiator2345 These tools generally are snake oil and don't improve anything.

Comment: Isn't [WEI](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-the-windows-experience-index) good enough? what sort of results were you expecting that WEI doesn't provide?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about a "performance" test. But you can check RAM for potential errors with a Ubuntu Live boot disk. (It's been there since at least Ubuntu version 9 that I can remember, and it's still there with the current 12.04 version.) Just choose to boot to the "Test Memory" selection when Grub comes up rather than the usual Ubuntu default. But be sure to press a key like the enter key when you first see the purple "Ubuntu" screen or else you won't see the boot menu. Memtest will also tell you other things like your CPU's L1/L2/L3 abilities as well as RAM timing, speed etc. It's not much to look at but I suspect this is what you want.

(BTW, Having an Ubuntu live boot disk is quite handy even if you never use it to install Ubuntu with. For example, the GParted utility alone can save hours of headaches. And even if all you can boot to is a TTY terminal you can still run the CFDISK utility for pretty much the same thing. And there are plenty more examples just like that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
winsat mem
```

iN cmd will give your RAM speed. That healped in analysing my RAM performance.